# Can't programmatically open up a jQuery Mobile PopUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to open up a jQuery Mobile popup.

Here's what I have:

```
        <div data-role="popup" class="ui-content" id="popupSave">
            <p>Comment saved.</p>
        </div>
```

And later on in some code, which gets executed, I have this:

```
$('#popupSave').popup("open");
```

So why is my popup not... well, popping up?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#popupSave').popup();
$('#popupSave').popup('open');
```

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mohamed_badr/fy2quhzd/1/

Comment: Works in the fiddle, but not in my code. Investigating further.

Comment: It works when I run it in the console. Perhaps something isn't initialized when I'm running it initially?

Comment: when you run your code do you receive any error in the console ?

Comment: when you call the popup in your code!? may be you are trying to call it before "pageshow"

Comment: Where does pageshow happen? I'm doing this after making a comment and saving it (all on the same page) so I would guess that yeah it's after pageshow, but I can check that.

Comment: yes in this case you call the popup after pageshow, my last suggestion is to call the popup in "onComplete" if you are saving the comment using ajax

Answer (score 1):

Found the actual solution.

```
setTimeout( function(){ $( '#popupSave' ).popup( 'open' ) }, 1 );
```

I'm guessing there's an error with Chrome like there is for other jQuery events.

I'll try to add it to my answer later on when I find out what it is - I had another issue like this with showing a mobile spinner.

Comment: I think this is a work around  not a  solution, if your code in ajax success try to move it to ajax complete or even after the ajax block but in this case you might need to check for a value you set in success to make sure that your code run correctly and the ajax request finished execution

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is related to another Chrome error, and there was no solution, just a workaround. I'll post the information later when I can find it.